# Firefox add-on backend code

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, erlang, firefox-addon

I thinking about creating a Firefox add-on but the problem is that as i can see add-on to Firefox is build with HTML and javascript that is not nearly powerful enough for my needs. So I was think what if i build a interface with this and then just write the rest of the program in a language that can do what I need. Then i just have the javascript call on methods in my main program and have it present the result.

The program language I had to mind to use was erlang, this language is however not mainstream and if it is not possible to do it with erlang I can settle for java. So assuming it is possible to do how do I go about doing this?

Comment: There's this thing called XPCOM. It connects javascript to C++ backend. So whatever C++ can do, and whatever is exposed via XPCOM, you can do it via javascript. If there is something not exposed, you can use js-ctypes to tap into it. What are you trying to make? I'm real certain you can't use java.

Comment: OOOh an XPCOM module to let firefox talk to erlang? I would love to have that

Answer (score 0):

They don't have an XPCOM module to talk to erlang. If you want, you can make a DLL for windows (and etc for other OS) then use js-ctypes to talk to your DLL to talk to erlang. Do you know how to make DLL?